# include <curl/curl.h> no such file or direcory

Tags: android, c++, curl, cross-compiling

I want to cross compile a c++ library to the android plateform for that i'am using the NDK standalone-toolchain
when scanning the dependencies of my library i've found that it depends on libcurl.

i've build libcurl for android my problem now is
when i try to  build my library i get include no such file or directory

knowing that i've added those lines in my CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(libcurl/include)
link_directories (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../neededLibs)
```

where .../neededLibs contains the libcurl.a compiled for android.

what do i have to do in order that my cross compiler recognizes ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `libcurl.a` will be used by the linker. You need to add include path, that will point to the headers, coming with `curl`.

Comment: but this is what i've done by
include_directories(libcurl/include)